# converting dateformat to MM-dd-yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

```
DateTime FourDaysBefore = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4);

DateTime Today = DateTime.Now;
string td = Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");        
DateTime CDate = Convert.ToDateTime(td);

DateTime EnteredDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datevalue);
string Edate = EnteredDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
DateTime txtdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Edate);

if (CDate.Month == txtdate.Month)
{
   if (FourDaysBefore.Day <= txtdate.Day)
      return false;
   else
      return true;
 }
 else
    return false;
```

In this code, `datevalue` is string and it's format is `dd-MM-yyyy`.

While converting `datevalue` to `DateTime` I get `"{10/8/2014 12:00:00 AM}"`.

After that i want to convert this to `"MM-dd-yyyy"` format. but I get `"10-08-2014"` where 10 is the day and 08 is the month.

Kindly help me to convert this `"{10/8/2014 12:00:00 AM}"` to `MM-dd-yyyy` format

Comment: Maybe `EnteredDate` is already the wrong date, what is the value of `datevalue` and what culture are you using(fe.e. en-us)?

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` - this isn't reading the date as expected.

Comment: I think it's better to use `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: `DateTime`s don't *have* a "format" - formatting issues only arise when working with *strings*. Therefore, whatever else is happening, the two lines starting at `string Edate` are at best achieving nothing and at worst corrupting the date value. Convert from a string once, early, and then just operate on the `DateTime` value.

Comment: I just using convert.todatetime, i didn't use datetime.parseexact

Comment: It is "expected behaviour", 10-08-2014 could either be the 10th of August 2014 or the 8th of October 2014. There is no way for the framework to determine which way round the month/day portion is in this particular format unless one of them is over 12. As Alizera said - use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) but ONLY if you are 100% sure that is the format that the user will enter the date in.

Answer (score 2):

This problem happen when you are converting base on different culture for fixing that you need use another ToDateTime function like below:

```
 CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");//Or en-UK base on the format
 DateTime CDate = Convert.ToDateTime(td,culture);
```

See the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you could try something like this:

```
DateTime startDatee = DateTime.Now;
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(startDatee.Month, startDatee.Day,    startDatee.Year, 08, 0, 0);
```

so startDatee = DateTime.Now which is: 14/08/2014

and then you could format this by creating an instance so:

```
new DateTime(startDatee.Month, startDatee.Day, startDatee.Year, 08, 0, 0);
```

will get you 08/14/2014

Answer (score 0):

You can split the date like this and transfer to an array.

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("M.d.yyyy");
string[] s_nowtime = s.Split('.');
```